# Alembic raises ImportError cannot import name '_NONE_NAME'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

When I rebuilt a Docker image for my Python application that uses SQLAlchemy and Alembic, I started getting the following error when running migrations:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_NONE_NAME' from 'sqlalchemy.sql.naming'
```

I didn't change my pinned requirements in `requirements.txt`. What is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to Alembic >= 1.10.2 resolves this, it fixed compatibility with SQLAlchemy < 1.3.24.

https://github.com/sqlalchemy/alembic/releases/tag/rel_1_10_2

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem since yesterday.

**Reproducing the problem locally:**
I noticed that creating a new venv and reinstalling the requirements reproduced the problem like in the container.

**Diagnosis:**
So, I created a new venv and reinstalled the requirements.txt.
Then i did pip freeze and compared the new installations to the pip freeze running on the old venv that was still working locally.
I found that alembic was installed witha  different versions.

**My solution:**
I downgraded alembic to be alembi==1.8.1 and now it works.

Hope this helps!